# Repository pattern and issue with base modal properties

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, repository-pattern, asp.net-core-3.1

I have created .NET core API with repository pattern and dependency injections.

This api uses already existing database and I have generated dbContext using scaffolding and issues starts with this.

- **The issue:** I want to handle some common column data insertion from service layer, like **CreationDateTime, CreationUserId** etc.
- This works perfectly fine if we use code-first approach since it allows us to inherit base modal class.
- But with data-first, we will have just plain modals.

Here is my base service layer.

```
public class BaseService<T> : IBaseService<T> where T : class, new()
{
    private readonly IBaseRepository<T> _repository;
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public BaseService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IBaseRepository<T> repository)
    {
        this._repository = repository;
        this._unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    public virtual Response<T> Insert(T model)
    {
        // TODO: can't access this columns since T is generic
        //model.CreationDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
        //model.CreationUserId = 1;

        var response = _repository.Add(model);
        _unitOfWork.Commit();
        return response;
    }
}
```

> What I did so far?

I know I can go to each service layer individually and update there, like below.

```
public class SurveyRequestService : BaseService<SurveyRequest>, ISurveyRequestService
{
    private readonly ISurveyRequestRepository _repository;
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public SurveyRequestService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, ISurveyRequestRepository repository)
        : base(unitOfWork, repository)
    {
        this._repository = repository;
        this._unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    public virtual Response<SurveyRequest> Insert(SurveyRequest model)
    {
        model.CreationDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
        model.CreationUserId = 1;

        var response = _repository.Add(model);
        _unitOfWork.Commit();
        return response;
    }
}
```

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You could consider using reflection as a last resort.

Comment: any example if you can give.

Comment: I don't get it ... with data-first  classes can be partial ... with partial you can derive from some **interface** in another file ... so where is the problem ?

Comment: If your T class is of a certain type, you can find a solution to your problem by adding this condition. Via this condition, you can access model.CreatedOn etc...  IBaseService<T> where T : BaseEntity, new()

Comment: @Selvin, yes that's right, but getting error when in SurveyRequestService like type cannot be used as parameter

Answer (score 0):

Try out this.

```cs
    class Entity: BaseEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    class BaseEntity
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    }

    class Service<T> where  T : BaseEntity, new()
    {
        public virtual void Insert(T model)
        {
            model.DateTime = DateTime.Now;
            model.UserId = 1;
        }
    }
```